# Vue FontAwesome icons don't change on compute

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I would like to change header icon based on conversation property.

```
<a class="navbar-item" :title="$t('header.lock')" @click="makePrivate">
    <i class="fas" :class="getLockClass"></i>
</a>
```

This is inside computed properties:

```
isConversationPrivate() {
    return !(Object.keys(this.conversation).length === 0 || this.conversation.user_id === null);
},
getLockClass() {
    console.log(this.isConversationPrivate);
    return this.isConversationPrivate ? 'fa-lock' : 'fa-unlock-alt';
}
```

So what happens is that when you load the page initially the conversation is empty, so the console log prints out `false` (non-existing conversation).

Axios request is made to fetch a conversation by ID, it is retrieved (using Vuex) and `getLockClass` runs again printing `true` in the console.

Even though the change happened, class never applied. Why doesn't it work?

EDIT:

I have managed to reproduce it on this example:

```
<html lang="fr">
<body>

<div id="app">
    <a @click="toggle">
        <i class="fas" :class="this.lock ? 'fa-lock':'fa-unlock'"></i>
    </a>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.0/js/all.min.js"></script>
<script>

    new Vue({
        el     : '#app',
        data   : {
            lock: true
        },
        methods: {
            toggle() {
                console.log("here");
                this.lock = !this.lock;
            }
        },
    });
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Did you use your  vue-devtools to make sure the property is actually not updating?
Even without, you can print what the return is giving you back.
If the return is what you expect, something is wrong with the class then I would say, either the style is not in the page or something down that line

Comment: The basic principle seems to work - see [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/whippet71/v1fw3p9q/). Have you inspected the element to see if the class is applied correctly?

Comment: If I manually apply the class, it shows on both cases, so dependencies are loaded correctly. The return does return good, however inspecting the element shows differently.

Comment: must be more to this than what we're seeing. Concept is correct, as others have poitned out.

Comment: What you have should work. And ***does work*** for anyone trying to repro it. Which means you haven't included the actual cause of your bug. Please provide a [mcve] which actually reproduces the bug so we could find the real cause and test any potential solutions against it. Without one, your question is not, technically, answerable. A wild guess here: have you made sure `isConversationPrivate` is changing as expected? We have no visibility over `conversation` object.

Comment: I understand the need for an example, but it would require a lot of files to reproduce. I edited the question to provide more data about the flow

Comment: Please take a look now, I managed to scrap it down to basics

Comment: I tried Chrome, incognito and Firefox. I'm on MacOs catalina. Not even fiddle from @JohnM is working...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your are using a FontAwesome library which will comment out the `<i>` element and replace it with an `<svg>`. You can check this if you inspect the element in your browser. FontAwesome recommends that you use `vue-fontawesome` for that and other reasons: https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/using-with/vuejs

Another solution would be to wrap the `<i>` inside another element (like a span):

```
<span v-show="lock"><i class="fas fa-lock"/></span>
<span v-show="!lock"><i class="fas fa-unlock"/></span>
```

Comment: You saved me! The second option doesn't work, but FA for Vue does the job. Thanks